# Android file splitter and joining is not work for apk file

Tags: java, android, file, filesplitting

I used this (https://github.com/huntergdavis/Easy_File_Split_And_Join) program to split and joining the files. Everything works perfect expect apk files. The program could successfully split and join video files and so on but fails to do the same for apk files. Kindly spot out the error in program. Also request to provide a correct code to split and join apk files too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apk files are just zip files, so you can use ZipInputStream to read them and ZipOutputStream to write them. There are plenty samples in the net explaining how to read and write zip files.

You can rename the apk to .zip and see the contents, if you want.